# How to change select options from js in this example

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I select the  tag option from the javascript/Angularjs backend.

Hint: I actually get data from API service, then I fill into a form to make them available for edit. Assume the gender is Male, how can I make the  tage becomes Male as it is in databse. So user can update it to Female for example.

Here is my codes:

```
$scope.Gender = [
{ GenderID: "Mmale", name: "Mmale" },
{ GenderID: "Female", name: "Female" }
];
```

HTML

```
<select class="form-control" name="Gender" ng-model="GenderID" ng-options="g.GenderID as g.name for g in Gender" required style="width:98px; color:gray">
                    <option value="" style="" >Gender?</option>
                </select>
```

Currently I use this to change the option but it does not work for me.

```
$scope.Gender.name = $scope.users[id].Gender;
$scope.Gender.GenderID = $scope.users[id].Gender;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a [working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/pkd5zp48/1), you only need to give the `ng-model` the `GenderID` you want to select:

HTML:

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <select class="form-control" name="Gender" ng-model="GenderID" ng-options="g.GenderID as g.name for g in Gender" required style="width:98px; color:gray">
        <option value="" style="" >Gender?</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function MyCtrl($scope, $filter) {
    $scope.Gender = [
        { GenderID: "Mmale", name: "Mmale" },
        { GenderID: "Female", name: "Female" }
    ];

    $scope.GenderID = "Mmale";
}
```